# Is there a limit to the number of work items in ADO?

Tags: azure-devops

We are running with ADO work items with 6 digits at the moment, is there a limit (can't believe there would be), or does it also allow 7 digits etc?

does ADO allow 7 digit work item numbers?

Answer (score 0):

> is there a limit (can't believe there would be), or does it also allow 7 digits etc?

As far as I know, there is no limit to the total number of work items in Azure DevOps Organization.

Refer to this doc: [Service and rate limits for Azure DevOps Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/service-limits?view=azure-devops)

And 7 digit work item numbers is allowed in Azure DevOps.

[image]